# Place custom Block, return Internal Server Error

Tags: blocks, 8, plugins

I create a Block Plugin in a module,
it be showing the available blocks but when I try to place the block, it returns in the browser console the follow error:

> AjaxError: 
>   An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
>   HTTP-resultaatcode: 500
>   Debug informatie volgt.
>   Pad: /admin/structure/block/add/hello_block/bartik?region=footer_fourth
>   Statustekst: Internal Server Error
>   Antwoordtekst:

I have place the code on the follow place:
DrupalRoot/modules/pagebuilder/src/Plugin/Block/testblock.php

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\pagebuilder\Plugin\Block\testblock.
 */
namespace Drupal\pagebuilder\Plugin\Block
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;

/**
 * Provides a 'Hello' Block
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "hello_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Hello block"),
 * )
 */
class testblock extends BlockBase {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function build() {
        return array(
            '#markup' => $this->t('Hello, World!'), 
        );
    }
}
?>
```

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Hi Andre van der Laan , I am facing the same error, would like to know how you fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

When developing and encounter 500 errors, you should see if Drupal has logged the error or your webserver has logged the error. Depending on your configuration you might be able to see a full stacktrace explaining the error.

In this case you are missing a `;` after your namespace declaration. So

`namespace Drupal\pagebuilder\Plugin\Block`

Should be

`namespace Drupal\pagebuilder\Plugin\Block;`

This should fix your error.

Comment: I ran into this issue. Following @googletorp's instructions lead me to an error that revealed I had the used the wrong namespace. `Drupal\example_module\Plugin\Block` instead of `Drupal\child_menu_list\Plugin\Block` ... in my example. Thanks for the reminder!